# Programmatically selecting/expanding a folder resource in Project Explorer

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

In Eclipse RCP, I'm programmatically creating a resource (folder with files) inside a Project, I wish to select and expand the folder (I know its path) in the Project Explorer (assuming it's opened). The effect should be similar than that of the "Link with Editor" button, but here the resource is not to be opened in an editor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First get the workbench page -

In a view or editor use:

```
IWorkbenchPage page = getSite().getPage();
```

elsewhere use

```
page = PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getActiveWorkbenchWindow().getActivePage();
```

Find the view, the `ProjectExplorer` view id is given in `IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER`

```
IViewPart view = page.findView(IPageLayout.ID_PROJECT_EXPLORER);
```

The project explorer view implements `ISetSelectionTarget` so you can do:

```
((ISetSelectionTarget)view).selectReveal(new StructuredSelection(object to show));
```

or in Java 16 onwards use a instanceof type pattern:

```java
if (view instanceof ISetSelectionTarget setSel) {
   setSel.selectReveal(new StructuredSelection(object to show));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But, recall that my "object to show" is not an UI element but a resource (say, an `IFolder`), would that work?

Comment: It should be expecting a resource

Comment: I tried passing it an `IFolder` and tt works as expected. Thanks!